# Terraform code will not create EC2 Instance

Tags: terraform

I'm new to Terraform and I'm trying to create my first resource. 
The provider is AWS and the provider download completed
I have run terraform init and that has completed.
However when I try to run terraform plan it tells me nothing in my infrastructure will change

```
provider "aws" {
  access_key = "I input my key here"
  secret_key = " I input my key here"
  region     = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_instance" "Server1" {
  ami           = "ami-0ea83ef2bc1efef82"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
}
```

Comment: Can you show the plan output even if it shows nothing? And the output of your Terraform state file?

Comment: When I run Terraform plan the output  just tells me "No changes. Infrastructure is up to date". "This means that terraform did not detect an differences between you conficguration and real physical resources that exist. As a result no actions need to be performed"

Comment: And what does your state file show?

Answer (score 0):

And that is correct.
"terraform plan" will just create execution plan, but it will not execute anything!

> The terraform plan command is used to create an execution plan. Terraform performs a refresh, unless explicitly disabled, and then determines what actions are necessary to achieve the desired state specified in the configuration files.
>   This command is a convenient way to check whether the execution plan for a set of changes matches your expectations without making any changes to real resources or to the state

[Terraform Plan](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html)

Now, post "terraform plan", what you have to do to create an AWS instance is hit "terraform apply"

"terraform apply" will pick the plan generated by "terraform plan" and will execute it on the provider mentioned. If its execution is successful, an EC2 instance will be created.

> The terraform apply command is used to apply the changes required to reach the desired state of the configuration, or the pre-determined set of actions generated by a terraform plan execution plan.

[Terraform Apply](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/apply.html)

Comment: Yes I know that terraform plan wont create anything but it should still show me an output of what it will create. However it does not show any output. It just tells me "No changes. Infrastructure is up to date". "This means that terraform did not detect an differences between you conficguration and real physical resources that exist. As a result no actions need to be performed"

Comment: If I try Terraform apply I get a message " Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed

Answer (score 0):

save the code and then
terraform init
and then terraform plan and apply!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).